# Creating multiple Text Layers on the Pebble Watchface App

Tags: c

I am trying to create a simple Watchface using custom fonts and a Bitmap image. 
When I just displayed the time,it was working fine.
I just used 1 TextLayer.

```
static TextLayer *s_time_layer;
```

Then I decided to add date and day in the display.
So I created 2 more TextLayers.

```
static TextLayer *s_day_layer,*s_date_layer;
```

After creating these two layers i was successfully able to display the day and date.But the watch stopped ticking.It shows the current time only once and then freezes.It shows the current time after I launch it again.

This is my function to update the time.

```
        static void update_time(struct tm *tick_time)
        {
          time_t temp = time(NULL);
          tick_time = localtime(&temp);

          static char buffer[6];
          static char daybuffer[9];
          static char datebuffer[] = "00-00-00";

          strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%I:%M", tick_time); //using 12 hr format
          text_layer_set_text(s_time_layer,buffer);

          strftime(daybuffer, sizeof(daybuffer), "%A", tick_time); 
          text_layer_set_text(s_day_layer, daybuffer); //display current day

          strftime(datebuffer, sizeof(datebuffer), "%d/%m/%y", tick_time); 
          text_layer_set_text(s_date_layer, datebuffer); //display current date

         }
```

Why is this happening?And how should I make my Clock tick?

Answer (score 0):

You defined `daybuffer[9]`, but the worst case is wednesday that is 9 chars long + `null` terminator.

This means that text_layer_set_text will invoke [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when will print your string.

Enlarge your buffer to `10` chars.

Take a look at [strftime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) ManPage

Where you can find

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> Provided that the result string, including the terminating null byte,
>          does not exceed max bytes, strftime() returns the number of bytes
>          (excluding the terminating null byte) placed in the array s.  **If the
>          length of the result string (including the terminating null byte)
>          would exceed max bytes, then strftime() returns 0, and the contents
>          of the array are undefined.**
>          Note that the return value 0 does not necessarily indicate an error.
>          For example, in many locales %p yields an empty string.  An empty
>          format string will likewise yield an empty string.